# Why did Dwight not inflate his title here?

Tags: the-office

Dwight K. Schrute, Assistant to the Regional Manager in *The Office* (US), has always introduced himself as Assistant Regional Manager.  When this happens, he is invariably corrected by either Michael or Jim that he is Assistant TO the Regional Manager.

In the episode Local Ad (S4 E9), Dwight is seen managing a persona in the virtual computer game, SecondLife.  His persona is named Dwight K. Schrute, a paper salesman.  His persona has the title "Asst To Regional Mgr."

Why would he not choose to title himself with the higher title in this game that he chooses in real life?

Comment: You just don't get Dwight :)

Answer (score 5):

> Why would he not choose to title himself with the higher title in this game that he chooses in real life?

#### Because it's not the truth!

The humor in that scene was that even though Dwight was playing a video game, literally every aspect about his character was the exact same as how he is in reality (except for the fact that he could fly... a joke made by Dwight himself).

It's within Dwight's nature to maintain honesty / integrity / respect authority. So, in that sense, **Dwight would have felt like he was lying if he had given his character the *"Assistant Regional Manager"* title without having properly earned it first.**

All of that being said, it's most likely the case that Dwight *knew* he would be corrected every time he referred to himself as ARM in reality (i.e., throughout the series), and the act of him doing so was simply to acknowledge / remind Michael and his coworkers that he's striving for a promotion and more authority in the office.